is it possible to fetch data into cpu cache while the cpu works on something else?
I wonder if its possible to improve performance by getting the cpu to load something into cache while it still works on something else. I'm not very knowledgeable about the inner workings of a cpu and not even sure if the cpu can just wait for some data while doing something with other data already loaded. But somehow I feel like the designers would have thought about something similar for the workings of a cpu cache.
for example if I'm travessing a linked list, I need to fetch the next node before I can work on it, but what if it was possible to prime the cpu
typedef struct LinkedList{
    LinkedList *next;
    float data[64];
} LinkedList;


void do_stuff(LinkedList *li){
    while (li){
        __somehow_prefetch_this_into_cache_async(li->next);
        for (int i=0; i < 64; i++){
            // do some very complicated work while the next item still is being loaded into cache
            li->data[i] += 1.0f;
        }
        li = li->next;
    }

}

I'm working on some performance sensitive code that requires me to travesse a linked list and after some profiling I noticed that around 30% of the time in the code is spent on the line that loads the next item from the pointer, which I suspect is just because of memory latency.

There's nothing like that in C++ itself (except for replacing LinkedList with an std::vector to make it contiguous in memory). There may be something in your chosen compiler or directly in the assembly you target.

fyi Portable explicit prefetch "...__builtin_prefetch..."

There are prefetch instructions but common wisdom today is that's no longer useful. Try to replace the linked list with a dynamic array or a deque

In my experience the software prefetch can be useful if you know you're likely to have cache misses at all levels, otherwise, probably better off without.

The linked list is fairly big and items get constantly swapped, so its practically guaranteed to have cache misses.
if I made it a contiguous array, I would have to move a LOT of data back and forth so I went for a linked list instead.

Well, without seeing the code we have to trust your judgement that a linked list is correct for you ;-) However, just note that arrays are so much faster than linked lists, you can often get away with using slightly worse algorithms and still be faster. Seeing the size of your list nodes (64 floats), an array of pointers to those nodes could be pretty good. It's still faster than a linked list for traversal since it still avoids the "pointer-chasing" problem of LLs.

@StackOverflowToxicityVictim "items get constantly swapped" -- You mean positions in the list get swapped, but the nodes themselves last a long time? Would it help to use a vector to allocate your nodes (each element of the vector is data plus a next pointer), but access them through head and next pointers? That would give some data locality to help with caching while still allowing the list to be split and spliced.

The main issue here is that you have a long dependency chain of indirect memory accesses which may not be in the cache. The time of the operation is the sum of the latency of all fetch. You can prefetch data but the long dependency chain is an issue because it means you need to do the operation twice. There is no way to make this chain faster besides moving node in memory before. The time of the prefetching will be at least the time of the computation.

You can prefetch the next nodes with a windows of few nodes like 16 nodes but the thing is the computation will certainly be so fast that the prefetching will be the bottleneck. In the end, the problem is the long dependency chain of slow fetches. One old strategy is to spawn a prefetching thread but honestly it makes the code harder to maintain and data will only be in the L3 cache because the thread is unlikely to be scheduled on the same code unless you bind threads to cores.

If the computation time takes a time close to the one of the fetch overhead then I advise you to try a basic prefetching-in-the-loop-with-a-window solution. Otherwise, this is a wast of time to try to do prefetching.

@Homer512 Prefetching is still useful nowadays! Here is an example. However, one need to think twice when using it because modern CPUs do a very good job and the benefit is often small (and yes it is brittle). It is useful for cache trashing issues and also when the fetched items cannot be predicted nor automatically prefetched (thanks to the large OoO window and speculative loads) by the CPU (which is the case here though the long dependency chain is an issue).

you could look into having two vectors.  one for the data and once that stores the order of the data.  That way swapping an element costs a swap in the index vector and traversal of the index vector will be cache friendly and the access into the vector has a chance as well.

Side note: a linked list is probably the worst datastructure you could choose (prefer arrays/vectors). Also, CPUs do prefetching all by themselves.

Although the impact of software prefetch on performance is indeed influenced by specific implementations and scheduling strategies, this scenario of point-chasing is a classic example where software prefetch can enhance performance. This is particularly true when the time consumption of your "complex tasks" remains relatively stable, as it allows for a fixed distance to be set for prefetching.
